# Professional sitecore 8 development - Gulp is not working

Tags: gulp, sitecore, visual-studio-2017

I've decided to have a look at the professional sitecore 8 Development bak and I am having issues at the end of chap 4, when the author explains how to setup gulp for the build - I have no experience with this tool.

Compared to the guide, I've had to amend some of the paths on my gulpfile.js because the routine was not finding the csproj files - I've noticed that on the file systems the solutions are NOT into folder (as I would have expected from the view in my solution).
Now I can run the task from My VS2017 but the task returns the error "MSBuild failed with code 1!".

Edit: I managed to make some progress following this link: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5344/when-using-gulp-to-build-a-helix-based-solution-what-does-msbuild-failed-with

My configuration now looks like the following:

```
/// <binding />
var gulp = require("gulp");
var msbuild = require("gulp-msbuild");
var debug = require("gulp-debug");
var foreach = require("gulp-foreach");
var gulpConfig = require("./gulp-config.js")();
module.exports.config = gulpConfig;
gulp.task("Publish-Site", function () {

    return gulp.src("./**/*.csproj")
        .pipe(foreach(function (stream, file) {
            return stream
                .pipe(debug({ title: "Publishing " }))
                .pipe(msbuild({
                    targets: ["Build"],
                    gulpConfiguration: gulpConfig.buildConfiguration,
                    properties: {
                        publishUrl: gulpConfig.webRoot,
                        DeployDefaultTarget: gulpConfig.webRoot,
                        WebPublishMethod: "FileSystem",
                        DeployOnBuild: "true",
                        DeleteExistingFiles: "false",
                        _FindDependencies: "false",
                        VisualStudioVersion: "15.0"
                    },
                    verbosity: "diagnostic",
                    toolsVersion: 15.0
                }));
        }));
});
```

but now when I try to run the task, I receive the error:

```
\SitecoreDev\Gulpfile.js" Publish-Site [16:28:54] Using gulpfile C:\VSTS\Sitecore8Dev\SitecoreDev\Gulpfile.js [16:28:54] Starting 'Publish-Site'... [16:28:55] Publishing  SitecoreDev\SitecoreDev.csproj [16:28:55] Publishing  1 item [16:28:55] { Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:192:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:374:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)   code: 'ENOENT',   errno: 'ENOENT',   syscall: 'spawn C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\MSBuild\\15.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe',   path: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\MSBuild\\15.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe',   spawnargs:     [ 'C:\\VSTS\\Sitecore8Dev\\SitecoreDev\\SitecoreDev\\SitecoreDev.csproj',
     '/target:Build',
     '/verbosity:diagnostic',
     '/toolsversion:15.0',
     '/nologo',
     '/maxcpucount',
     '/property:Configuration=Release',
     '/property:publishUrl=C:\\Websites',
     '/property:DeployDefaultTarget=C:\\Websites\\',
     '/property:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem',
     '/property:DeployOnBuild=true',
     '/property:DeleteExistingFiles=false',
     '/property:_FindDependencies=false',
     '/property:VisualStudioVersion=15.0' ] } [16:28:55] MSBuild failed! [16:28:55] MSBuild failed with code -4058! [16:28:55] 'Publish-Site' errored after 1.26 s error! [16:28:55] Error: no writecb in Transform class
    at afterTransform (C:\VSTS\Sitecore8Dev\SitecoreDev\node_modules\gulp-foreach\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:95:33)
    at TransformState.afterTransform (C:\VSTS\Sitecore8Dev\SitecoreDev\node_modules\gulp-foreach\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:79:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.<anonymous> (C:\VSTS\Sitecore8Dev\SitecoreDev\node_modules\gulp-foreach\index.js:60:9)
    at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at C:\VSTS\Sitecore8Dev\SitecoreDev\node_modules\gulp-msbuild\index.js:25:12
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\VSTS\Sitecore8Dev\SitecoreDev\node_modules\gulp-msbuild\lib\msbuild-runner.js:57:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16) Process terminated with code 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I will post it here in case somebody has the same issue:

1) Update gulp msbuild to the last version. This is how the package.json should look like:

```
{
  "name": "sitecoredev",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.12.3",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.2.4",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.1.7",
    "gulp-debug": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-foreach": "^0.1.0",
    "gulp-install": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-msbuild": "^0.5.2",
    "gulp-newer": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-rimraf": "^0.1.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.5",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "author": ""
}
```

2) update the gulpfile.js as per following:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var msbuild = require("gulp-msbuild");
var debug = require("gulp-debug");
var foreach = require("gulp-foreach");
var gulpConfig = require("./gulp-config.js")();
module.exports.config = gulpConfig;

gulp.task("Publish-Site", function () {
    return gulp.src("./**/*.csproj")
        .pipe(foreach(function (stream, file) {
            return stream
                .pipe(debug({ title: "Publishing " }))
                .pipe(msbuild({
                    targets: ["Build"],
                    properties: {
                        publishUrl: gulpConfig.webRoot,
                        DeployDefaultTarget: "WebPublish",
                        WebPublishMethod: "FileSystem",
                        DeployOnBuild: "true",
                        DeleteExistingFiles: "false",
                        _FindDependencies: "false"
                    },
                    verbosity: "diagnostic",
                    toolsVersion: 15.0
                }));
        }));
});
```

and it should now work.